# TensorFlow - how to stop TensorBoard from command line in Windows?

Tags: tensorflow

If I put the following at the end of a TensorFlow Python program:

```
# show the result in TensorBoard
tfFileWriter = tf.summary.FileWriter(os.getcwd())
tfFileWriter.add_graph(sess.graph)
tfFileWriter.close()
```

I get a file in the same directory that is titled something like:

```
events.out.tfevents.1513529946.DESKTOP-KR0HCRR
```

Then I open a command prompt and enter:

> tensorboard --logdir C:\Users\cdahms\Documents\TensorFlowExample9

I get the output from the command line:

```
TensorBoard 0.1.8 at http://DESKTOP-KR0HCRR:6006 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

If I open a broswer and go to `http://localhost:6006` I get the expected TensorBoard graph.

Problem is, if I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> the process from the command line does not quit as the TensorBoard output indicates.  Here is a screenshot if that would be helpful:

[image]

I gather the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> must be for Linux and/or Mac but does not work in Windows.  I've also tried <kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>, and pretty much every other combination of keystroke to stop a process that I've ever known of.

Is there a combination of keystroke(s) that can stop TensorBoard on Windows?

To clarify I'm using Windows 10 and PyCharm as an editor (I'm not using a Jupyter Notebook)

Also, before somebody responds "just close that command line window and that will end TensorBoard, then open another command line window" yes, of course I understand I can do that, however it would be preferable to be able to stop TensorBoard from the command line and then re-start it after changing a script without having to close/re-open a new command line window.

Comment: What about `Ctrl+D`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but Ctrl+D does not work either.  I wonder if this is a bug I should post on the TensorFlow GitHub?

Comment: `Ctrl+C` *should* work in Windows.  I'm using Windows 7 with TensorBoard 0.4.0rc3 and it works for me.  If you run a Python script with an infinite loop, does `Ctrl+C` stop that?

Comment: Ctrl+C does work, I found I had to press Ctrl+C multiple times usually, or alternatively press Ctrl+Pause/Break pretty much always works the first time, see the answer I posted below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Per this response from nfelt, I found that if I pressed Ctrl+C multiple times, usually 2 or 3, that would stop tensorboard.  Also as nfelt mentioned I found that Ctrl + Pause/Break almost always stopped tensorboard immediately.